# Как добавить поддомен в Pdd.yandex.ru?

Tags: dns, домен, поддомены

Есть домен site.ru, который привязан к DNS-хостингу Яндекса, A записи которого указывают на ip хостинга 1. Мне нужно сделать поддомен shop.site.ru, который должен работать на хостинге 2. Достаточно ли будет сделать DNS -запись следующего вида?

```
shop A ip2
```

Comment: Долго писать ответ... Напишу коммент. Да, достаточно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже не знаю как подлиннее написать :)

Да, этого достаточно, в случаях если позже не заходите более глубокую вложенность делать, типа www.shop.site.ru.

Comment: А если захочет?

Comment: @Qwertiy Тогда думаю комментарий напишет и мне придется расписывать поднятие DNS сервера и настройку NS записей в основном домене. Хотя может яндекс сможет поддомен поддерживать , это уже копать надо